# .map() is not mapping (generating <div> with .map())

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, methods, iterable

#### What I was trying to make...

[image: IterableBox]

#### Code...

```
const programmingSkillsDetails = [
  { skill: "JavaScript", ratingPercentage: 85 },
  { skill: "React JS", ratingPercentage: 85 },
  { skill: "React Native", ratingPercentage: 85 },
  ...
];


...



<div
  className="resume-screen-container programming-skills-container"
  key="programming-skills"
>
    {programmingSkillsDetails.map((skill, index) => {
        <div className="skill-parent" key={index}>
          <div className="heading-bullet"></div>
          <span>{skill.skill}</span>
          <div className="skill-percentage">
              <div
                style={{ width: skill.ratingPercentage + "%" }}
                className="active-percentage-bar"
              ></div>
          </div>
       </div>;
    })}
</div>
```

#### Output...

[image: Output]

##### Renders the parent "screen-container" `<div>` ... but doesn't map children `<div>`'s

#### Recognizes the `skill.skill` and `skill.ratingPercentage`

[image]

Comment: You need to actually `return` the JSX inside your `map` callback function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is because your map function returns nothing.**

Map function takes a callback function as a parameter, and this callback have to return something if you want to display something in the DOM.
Here is some more informations: https://linguinecode.com/post/how-to-use-map-react

**Do this instead:**

```
{programmingSkillsDetails.map((skill, index) => 
        <div className="skill-parent" key={index}>
          <div className="heading-bullet"></div>
          <span>{skill.skill}</span>
          <div className="skill-percentage">
              <div
                style={{ width: skill.ratingPercentage + "%" }}
                className="active-percentage-bar"
              ></div>
          </div>
       </div>
    )}
```

**Or you could also write it like this:**

```
{programmingSkillsDetails.map((skill, index) => {
   return <div className="skill-parent" key={index}>
          <div className="heading-bullet"></div>
          <span>{skill.skill}</span>
          <div className="skill-percentage">
              <div
                style={{ width: skill.ratingPercentage + "%" }}
                className="active-percentage-bar"
              ></div>
          </div>
       </div>}
         )}
```

**Or like this:**

```
{programmingSkillsDetails.map((skill, index) => {
   return (<div className="skill-parent" key={index}>
          <div className="heading-bullet"></div>
          <span>{skill.skill}</span>
          <div className="skill-percentage">
              <div
                style={{ width: skill.ratingPercentage + "%" }}
                className="active-percentage-bar"
              ></div>
          </div>
       </div>)}
         )}
```